# How to remove column duplication in PySpark DataFrame without declare column name where the columns are unknown to me?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have one source data:

employee_id   employee_name  salary     designation
101           monali         70000      developer
102           Amy            70000      developer
103           neha           65000      tester

I have a schema :
["employee_id","employee_name","salary","designation" ]

Now I got 1 extra column in the source data which is unknown to me, so it is not in the schema/metadata.

employee_id   employee_name  salary     designation    gender
101           monali         70000      developer
102           Amy            70000      developer
103           neha           65000      tester
104           amar           76000      developer       male

I need to write this extra column along with the records where the extra columns are present without selecting the valid columns. This column is ever changing, so I can't define this column as "Gender" in the code.

Note: Here valid column means the columns which are determined by metadata/schema and invalid columns/extra columns can be defined as which are not present in metadata.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, let's say now we have schema : `["employee_id","employee_name","salary","designation" , "designation"]`, your want to remove the duplicate column name, i.e. `designation`, OR you have a new schema `["employee_id","employee_name","salary","designation" , "gender"]`, you want to drop the duplicate row based on the unknown new column `gender`?

Comment: I don't have the column name, it is unknown to me. so it is not in metadat. I have provided "Gender" just for a reference. It will change everytime one or other columns are getting added which is not in schema.